# Can cell division be stopped during prophase?

Tags: cell-biology, mitosis

There are three known checkpoints which ensure proper division of the cell.

> These are: the G1 checkpoint, also known as the restriction or start checkpoint or (Major Checkpoint); the G2/M checkpoint; and the metaphase checkpoint, also known as the spindle checkpoint.

I wanted to know that is there any way cell division can be stopped during prophase(once it has started).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unaware of such stop occurring at a mitotic prophase, but if your definition of "cell division" includes meiosis, the answer is yes: in several species, the oocyte stops at the first prophase (prophase I), in a resting phase called "dictyotene": https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictyate

Comment: Yes exactly right.